# Whitespace appearing using CSS :after and :content

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to style the output of `wp_list_categories` using CSS to put commas in between items. However, there is a whitespace appearing before the comma and I seriously cannot comprehend where it is coming from!

I have made a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iyohis/2/) to demonstrate and compare.

Screenshot:
[image]

HTML:

```
<ul id="category-listing">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-6"><a href="#" title="View all posts filed under Branding">Branding</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-4"><a href="#" title="View all posts filed under Environment">Environment</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-5"><a href="#" title="View all posts filed under Exhibition">Exhibition</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-8"><a href="#" title="View all posts filed under Lecture">Lecture</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-9"><a href="#" title="View all posts filed under Photography">Photography</a>
</li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-10"><a href="#" title="View all posts filed under Print">Print</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
  font-size: 46px;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#category-listing li:after {
  content: ', ';
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The white space is appearing because it is there in your HTML code.

The closing `</li>` tag is on a new line. Carriage returns are counted as white space in HTML, and therefore you have white space at the end of the list item element.

The reason it is showing up is because you're using `display:inline`. When usign `inline` (or `inline-block`), white space is relevant because `inline` means "treat this element as plain text", and therefore any white space is considered an intentional part of the text.

The best way to get rid of this is to simply put the `</li>` closing tag on the same line as the rest of the text, so that there is no white space there.

There are a number of other ways around it, but most of them involve quite hacky CSS; simply closing up the space is by far the easiest option.

The next best alternative is to switch to using `float:left` instead of `display:inline`. This will also deal with the problem, but will change the way the whole thing is rendered, which will require you to make various other changes to your CSS to compensate.

Comment: Thank you for the descriptive explanation. The newlines were inserted by the `wp_list_categories` function but I've stripped them with a str_replace `str_replace("\n", '', $snip);`. Perfect, thank you!

Comment: Actually, in this particular case, there's a really simple css solution without using floats, at least for modern browsers: `#category-listing li a:after { content: ' '; font-size: 0;}`

Comment: I was afraid of this, and suppose I have to live with really long lines of HTML. It's sad that my options seem to be ugly HTML or hacky CSS. I was hoping there'd be some kind of 'trim' function in CSS to get around tihs.

Comment: @MichaelScheper Please bear in mind that this answer is several years old now. There have been things added to CSS in the meanwhile that may help you, and some options are now available because we no longer have to support older browsers. The browser world in 2017 is quite different to the one we had to deal with in 2013.

Comment: @Spudley: I'm happy to hear it! Can you link to an up-to-date answer? There doesn't seem to be one here.

Comment: To be honest, I think the correct answer to the original question is to put the comma style on the `a` tag instead of the `li`.... ie `a:after{ ... }` instead of `li:after { ...}`. Not sure why I didn't spot that when I originally answered the question, but if you're looking to do the same thing, try that. The more generic answer that you're probably after is to use CSS `display:flex` instead of `display:inline`. You may need to make other changes as well to go with it, and I don't have time to go into great detail, but look it up and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

FLoating the anchor  inside the list item will solve this issue:

```
li a {float:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have `spaces` with `inline` display. You have two choices:

1. Remove spaces:

   ```
   <ul id="category-listing">
       <li class="cat-item cat-item-6"><a href="#" title="View all posts filed under Branding">Branding</a>
   </li><li class="cat-item cat-item-4"><a href="#" title="View all posts filed under Environment">Environment</a>
   </li><li class="cat-item cat-item-5"><a href="#" title="View all posts filed under Exhibition">Exhibition</a>
   </li><li class="cat-item cat-item-8"><a href="#" title="View all posts filed under Lecture">Lecture</a>
   </li><li class="cat-item cat-item-9"><a href="#" title="View all posts filed under Photography">Photography</a>
   </li><li class="cat-item cat-item-10"><a href="#" title="View all posts filed under Print">Print</a></li>
   </ul>
   ```
2. Use `float`:

   ```
   ul {overflow: hidden;}
   ul li {float: left;}
   ```

Comment: Ok, I'm deleting my answer since this guy explained it better, just take a look a this article, really useful: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same problem by use span tag for content:

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-6"><a href="#" title="View all posts filed under Branding"><span>Branding</span></a>
```